# Using Entity Framework & Linq to retrieve inserted ID with DomainCollectionView

Tags: c#, silverlight, entity-framework, mvvm, mvvm-light

I'm using Entity Framework in Silverlight 4.0. When a user enters a keyword on my form, I check my `EntityList<Keyword>` see if the keyword exists or not. If not, I add it to the database & refresh my EntityList. I'm not sure if the way I'm doing it is 100% on track with best practice.

I'm using an MVVM-Friendly DomainDataSource, the DataCollectionView, thanks to [Kyle McClellan](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kylemc/archive/2010/12/02/introducing-an-mvvm-friendly-domaindatasource-the-domaincollectionview.aspx). Here is my code for loading my keywords entity, in my constructor (with declarations above):

```
private readonly MI2DomainContext _context = new MI2DomainContext();
private readonly DomainCollectionView<Keyword> _keywordView;
private readonly DomainCollectionViewLoader<Keyword> _keywordLoader;
private readonly EntityList<Keyword> _keywordSource;
private int enteredKeywordID = 0;

public ProvisionDashboardViewModel()
{
    this._keywordSource = new EntityList<Keyword>(this._context.Keywords);
    this._keywordLoader = new DomainCollectionViewLoader<Keyword>(LoadKeywords, LoadKeywordsCompleted);
    this._keywordView = new DomainCollectionView<Keyword>(this._keywordLoader, this._keywordSource);
    this._keywordView.MoveToFirstPage();
}
```

After a user enters a keyword and clicks Search, I use commanding to call a method containing this code, where 'searchText' contains the user-entered value to search for. This creates a new instance of my Keyword class, adds it to my context, submits the changes, including the callback function upon completion:

```
enteredKeywordID = (int)(from d in this._keywordSource.Source where d.keyword.ToLower() == searchText.ToLower() select d.keywordID).FirstOrDefault();
if (0 == enteredKeywordID) {
    Keyword kw = new Keyword() { keyword = searchText };
    this._context.Keywords.Add(kw);
    this._context.SubmitChanges(KeywordsAddedCompleted, null);
}
```

The callback function iterates through the AddedEntities collection (of 1) and sets the enteredKeywordID value. It then sends out a message using MVVM-light messaging to call an API that uses the keyword search entered earlier. This API returns data that is later saved to my database, requiring the enteredKeywordID variable set here:

```
private void KeywordsAddedCompleted(SubmitOperation so)
{
    if (so.HasError)
    {
        so.MarkErrorAsHandled();
     }
     else
     {
         foreach (Keyword item in so.ChangeSet.AddedEntities) {
             enteredKeywordID = item.keywordID;
         }
        Messenger.Default.Send<string>(SearchText, "GenerateKeywords");     
     }
  }
```

Is there a better way to do this?